# How does the bitwise AND help in the if statements in the Linux Kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

**Background on what the code is trying to achieve:**
"*Various parameters of the new process (e.g., euid, egid, argument list, environment, filename, etc.) that
are subsequently passed to other functions are, for the sake of simplicity, combined into a structure of
type linux_binprm. prepare_binprm is used to supply a number of parent process values (above all, the
effective UID and GID); the remaining data — the argument list — are then copied manually into the
structure. Note that prepare_binprm also takes care of handling the SUID and SGID bits:*"

**fs/exec.c**

```
int prepare_binprm(struct linux_binprm *bprm)
{
...
    bprm->e_uid = current->euid;
    bprm->e_gid = current->egid;
if(!(bprm->file->f_vfsmnt->mnt_flags & MNT_NOSUID)) {
/* Set-uid? */
    if (mode & S_ISUID) {
    bprm->e_uid = inode->i_uid;
}
/* Set-gid? */
/*
* If setgid is set but no group execute bit then this
* is a candidate for mandatory locking, not a setgid
* executable.
*/
if ((mode & (S_ISGID | S_IXGRP)) == (S_ISGID |      S_IXGRP)) {
      bprm->e_gid = inode->i_gid;
  }
}
...
}
```

Here, the bitwise AND (&) is being used in the if-statement to analyze the flags. But what does this achieve? As in, what is the condition its checking and how is it evaluated?

Source: Linux Kernel Architecture

Comment: I know what the bitwise AND is but what I don't understand is, how are the conditions evaluated? Like, what is *if(mode & S_ISUID)* trying to check?

Comment: The condition checks if `S_ISGID` or `S_IXGRP` are set in `mode`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude set in *mode* as in?

Comment: @4386427 Essentially what my question is, is, what does the line (mode & S_ISUID) check? When does it return true and when false?

Comment: `S_ISGID` and `S_IXGRP` represents individual *bits*. The condition check is those *bits* are set in the value of `mode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of bitwise and expression `a & b` is a number with value 1 at every bit that is set in both `a` and `b`, and value 0 at all other bits.  If that result is exactly equal to `b` (for example) then it must be the case that every bit that is set in `b` is also set in `a`.  If the result is unequal to `b` then there must be at least one bit set in `b` that is not set in `a`.

In your particular example, `mode` is a file mode bitmask, `S_ISGID` is a macro representing the set-group-id bit of such a mask, and `S_IXGRP` is a macro representing the group-executable bit of such a mask.  The condition then evaluates whether both the `S_ISGID` bit and the `S_IXGRP` bit are set in `mode`.  If a regular file has a mode for which that is the case then that file is a setgid executable.